# Quaternion animation doesn’t animate

Tags: uwp

I’m trying to do a quaternion animation in the visual layer. But then I run the code it doesn’t animate, it just jumps between the two states. I’m doing something wrong?

```
        var compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this).Compositor;

        var visual = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();

        visual.Size = new Vector2(25, 25);
        visual.Offset = new Vector3(150, 150, 0);
        visual.Brush = compositor.CreateColorBrush(Colors.Green);

        ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(this, visual);

        var orientationAnimation = compositor.CreateQuaternionKeyFrameAnimation();
        orientationAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(0f, new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0));
        orientationAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(0.25f, new Quaternion(0, 1, 2, 3));
        orientationAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(0.75f, new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0));
        orientationAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        orientationAnimation.IterationBehavior = AnimationIterationBehavior.Forever;

        visual.StartAnimation(nameof(visual.Orientation), orientationAnimation);

        visual.StartAnimation(nameof(visual.Orientation), orientationAnimation);
```

Animations like scaling works fine:

```
        var scaleAnimation = compositor.CreateVector3KeyFrameAnimation();

        scaleAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(0f, new Vector3(1, 1, 0));
        scaleAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(1f, new Vector3(4, 4, 0));
        scaleAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3500);
        scaleAnimation.IterationBehavior = AnimationIterationBehavior.Forever;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But then I run the code it doesn’t animate, it just jumps between the two states.

For "it just jumps between the two states", this effect should just be the result animation by running the above code snippet. "Jump" may be caused by the duration is too short to animate, The "two" states are depend on how  you define the  `Quaternion` values for the key frames.

I'm not sure what's the exactly effects you want, but I guess the reason you didn't think it is animated is that the animation doesn't show an obviously  smoothly rotation. In that case, you could try to change the `Quaternion` values for the key frames to rotate with other angles for a testing. And also add a longer duration to let the animation showed obviously. For example:

```
ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(GlassHost, visual);
var orientationAnimation = compositor.CreateQuaternionKeyFrameAnimation();
orientationAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(0f, new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0));
// Create a Quaternion that represents a 45 degree rotation around X Axis
orientationAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(0.25f, new Quaternion(0.380f, 0f, 0.0f, 0.92f));
orientationAnimation.InsertKeyFrame(0.75f, new Quaternion(1f, 1f, 0f, 0f));          
orientationAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000);
orientationAnimation.IterationBehavior = AnimationIterationBehavior.Forever;
visual.StartAnimation(nameof(visual.Orientation), orientationAnimation);
```

For more details please reference [`QuaternionKeyFrameAnimation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.quaternionkeyframeanimation), for calculating the [`Quaternion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.numerics.quaternion) to meet your requierements please try it yourself since it needs the complex mathematics calculation.

Comment: Thanks, looks like (0, 0, 0, 0) is an invalid quaternion or something like that, all other values seems to be fine. Maybe I should learn how this works :-). I find the helper method Quaternion.CreateFromYawPitchRoll which is useful.